# rest implementation without annotations

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to learn REST web services. But it seems to use annotations every where. Is there any implementation of Rest framework without using annotations.I have no idea about annotations.

Thanks

Comment: what is so bad about asking a question on easy way for those who dont know annotations?? Every tutorial which i referred seems to be aimed at pro kind of people, where they assume a lot during explanation..

Answer (score 2):

REST does not use annotations. REST is just a spec of good wishes. It does not dictate anything. You are right: the most of existing *implementations* user annotations. And IMHO it is good.

But if you do not want to use them implement REST yourself. It is easy. For POST create servlet that impelments `doPost()`. Extract data from URL. Call underlying layer with these parameters. For GET method implement `doGet()` that does pretty the same.

This is the idea of REST. Nothing more. What frameworks do is just the parsing of the arguments and marshalling/unmarshalling of data. But if you data is marshalled as XML or JSON (or any other format) you can implement all this yourself very quickly.

Happy RESTing!

Comment: Thanks alex. Can u direct me to a place where i can find the rest implementation of both server and client based on doPost and doGet.